# Custom filter for an ng dynamic table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have a dynamic ngTable for which I created a custom datetime filter like this:

```
// Generate table columns.

function generateColumns(sampleData) {
    var colNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sampleData);
    var cols = colNames.map(function (name, idx) {
    if (name == 'date') {
        var filter = {};
        filter[name] = 'partials/dateFilter.tpl.html';
        return {
           title: name,
           sortable: name,
           filter: filter,
           filterOptions: { filterFn: dateFilter },
           filterLayout: "horizontal",
           show: true,
           field: name
        };
   } 
...
```

This way in my table, on the correct column I can see a datepicker instead of the usual text input for a filter.

My table data is initialized by simply doing:

```
// Initialize table parameters.
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page.
    count: 25 // counts per page.
}, {
    filterDelay: 0,
    dataset: $scope.testDataList
});
```

What I dont know how to do though is actually filter the data once I pick a date. My `dateFilter` function right now only contains a `log` message, but it is never called.

Basically the fact that I will change the date on my element but ngTable does not react in some way is by biggest issue.

How can I filter the table content based on the selected date?